# Application not working after including AOP in Weblogic server

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, weblogic12c

We are creating a war and deploying it on weblogic server and The application works fine but if we enable AOP, we get nullpointer exception when we hit the URL. This issue is only with "Weblogic". The application still works fine after enabling AOP in ApacheTomcat.

The error comes only when we include "aop:aspectj-autoproxy" tag in ApplicationContext.xml and deploy in WEBLOGIC server.

Other properties are :
jdk.version-1.7
aspectjrt.version-1.7.0
aspectjtools-1.7.0
weblogicServer-12c

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

What is the reason ?

Comment: aspectj library version conflict? check that Weblogic does not include its own aspect library

Comment: Adding the stack trace of the `NullPointerException`, so we know where it happened would probably help.

Comment: Not just the stack trace, but ideally an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), please. "It does not work" does not qualify as a question, this is not a quiz.